# Can Wasps smell fear?

Tags: human-biology, wasps

There are two conflicting things I have heard. One more anecdotal:

> Wasps can smell when you are afraid of them

The other from reading popular science magacines:

> Humans don't produce any pheromones

As far as I know, a pheromone is a smell produced to communicate with members of your own, but also other species. From my understanding these two statements are mutually exclusive.

So: **Can wasps smell if a human is afraid?**

Any answer with sources is appreciated.

Comment: If anyone with enough reputation would be so kind to create a [pheromones] tag, that would be great ;)